# How to start Quicktime X screen recording with specific size

Tags: applescript, quicktime

In Quicktime Player X, when you want to start a screen recording, you can either record the whole screen or drag to select a region. In the latter case, if you want a specific size (e.g., 1280x720), the best you can do is guess as you are dragging the mouse.

Can I use AppleScript to tell Quicktime Player to select a specific region size? I'll be happy to drag it into its final location manually, but if I could at least automate the part of initially specifying the region size, I'd be happy.

Is this possible? Where do I start looking for documentation?

Comment: Probably it's not what you want (which is why this isn't an answer, merely a comment), but there's a terrific cheap screen recording application called iShowU http://www.shinywhitebox.com/ishowu-hd/

I'm afraid custom selection rectangles are not part of the features of QuickTime Player. At least nothing of the sort is to be found in its AppleScript dictionary.